# why i got this message[“Variable name” cannot be resolved to a variable]?

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, binary

I am writing a code about finding the parent for a specified node (in BST). I wrote it but it doesn't work! I use Eclipse using Java,and i get this error:

```
"parent" cannot be resolved to a variable.
```

i wonder how to solve this problem? (i am kinda new to java, thanks in advance)

There is my code:

```
public TreeNode<E> getParent(TreeNode<E> node) {
    TreeNode<E> parent = null;
    TreeNode<E> current = root;

    while (current != null) {
        if (((Comparable<E>)node).compareTo((E)current) < 0) {
            parent = current;
            current = current.left;
        } else if (((Comparable<E>) node).compareTo((E)current) > 0) {
            parent = current;
            current = current.right;
        } else {
            break;
        }
     }

    size++;
    return parent;

}
```

Comment: it appear when i wrote: System.out.print("\nthe parent of" + list.search(5) + parent); - to get for example the parent for the node 5 - ?

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, "it appear when i wrote: `System.out.print("\nthe parent of" + list.search(5) + parent)`" and the fact, that this line does not appear in the method that you posted in your question, the conclusion is:

You are trying to access a method's local variable in another place - for example in another method. You should learn about scope. Search for it. Good starting point is the link in Aniket's comment.

Quick solution to your problem: It seems that you want to print a parent of a specific node in your tree. Therefore you already wrote the method `getParent` that returns exactly that parent. You cannot access the parent variable (because it is known only during the method's execution), but you can use the method's return value:

```
TreeNode node = list.search(5); // didn't use type parameter here
System.out.print("The parent of " + node + ": " + getParent(node));
```

Comment: I tried this: TreeNode<E> node = 5;
     System.out.print("The parent of " + node + ": " + getParent(node)); but i got again an error message: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E !! - width: TreeNode node = list.search(5); --> i had to change return type of search() to TreeNode.

Comment: You cannot use the type `E` here. You must use the same parameter type as in the initialization of your `list`.

Comment: I had to do this otherwise i have to change modifier of "getParent()" to 'static' and i don't really want it!